# Permission denied error when trying to shutil.copy folders from one destination to another?

Tags: python

Trying to run a simple code that transfer folders from one destination to another however i'm getting a permission error:

```py
>>> import shutil
>>> location = 'C:\\Users\\user\\files'
>>> dest = 'C:\\Users\\user\\transfer'
>>> my_array = ['folder1','folder2']
>>>
>>> for folder in my_array:
...     shutil.copy('{}\{}'.format(location, folder), '{}'.format(dest))
```

error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\env\lib\shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\env\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\files\\folder1'
```

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` to combine directory with filename, not string formatting.

Comment: Try to use raw strings with single '\', e.g.: location = r'C:\Users\user\files' and r'{}\{}'

Answer (score 9):

`shutil.copy()` is for copying a single file. If you want to copy a whole folder, use [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree).

You need to append the directory name to the destination as well, it won't do this automatically.

```
shutil.copytree(os.path.join(location, folder), os.path.join(dest, folder))
```

`os.path.join()` is preferable to `format()` when concatenating pathname components.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

```
shutil.copytree(OriPath, DstPath, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real permission issue, you should use `os.chmod()` function to change the permissions.

**Code line:**

```
os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IROTH)
```

Here is the documentation of flags (`stat` module): https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html

The following flags can also be used in the mode argument of `os.chmod()`:

```
stat.S_ISUID Set UID bit.

stat.S_ISGID Set-group-ID bit. This bit has several special uses. For a directory it indicates that BSD semantics is to be used for that directory: files created there inherit their group ID from the directory, not from the effective group ID of the creating process, and directories created there will also get the S_ISGID bit set. For a file that does not have the group execution bit (S_IXGRP) set, the set-group-ID bit indicates mandatory file/record locking (see also S_ENFMT).

stat.S_ISVTX Sticky bit. When this bit is set on a directory it means that a file in that directory can be renamed or deleted only by the owner of the file, by the owner of the directory, or by a privileged process.

stat.S_IRWXU Mask for file owner permissions.

stat.S_IRUSR Owner has read permission.

stat.S_IWUSR Owner has write permission.

stat.S_IXUSR Owner has execute permission.

stat.S_IRWXG Mask for group permissions.

stat.S_IRGRP Group has read permission.

stat.S_IWGRP Group has write permission.

stat.S_IXGRP Group has execute permission.

stat.S_IRWXO Mask for permissions for others (not in group).

stat.S_IROTH Others have read permission.

stat.S_IWOTH Others have write permission.

stat.S_IXOTH Others have execute permission.

stat.S_ENFMT System V file locking enforcement. This flag is shared with S_ISGID: file/record locking is enforced on files that do not have the group execution bit (S_IXGRP) set.

stat.S_IREAD Unix V7 synonym for S_IRUSR.

stat.S_IWRITE Unix V7 synonym for S_IWUSR.

stat.S_IEXEC Unix V7 synonym for S_IXUSR.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
```

works for me

Comment: Why do you prefer this over e.g. `copytree()` used in the top-voted answer?

Comment: @JeremyCaney i am trying to copy a single file instead of the folder

Comment: But the question is explicitly about folders, which is why `copy()` hadn’t worked.

Comment: @JeremyCaney yeah, `copyfile` not for copy folder...