# Permission denied by shutil.copy() when copying a directory instead of a file

Tags: python, shutil

This is the code I executed:
`shutil.copy(r'd:\try',r'd:\new')`
The output I got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
shutil.copy(r'd:\try',r'd:\new')
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 415, in copy
copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'd:\\try'
```

I get this permission error only when I try to copy folders but this error doesn't occur when I copy a file. How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied error when trying to shutil.copy folders from one destination to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914100/permission-denied-error-when-trying-to-shutil-copy-folders-from-one-destination)

Answer (score 2):

As can be read in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy), `shutil.copy()` is used for copying **files**.

To copy a **directory**, use `shutil.copytree()` instead:

```py
shutil.copytree(r'd:\try', r'd:\new')
```